# Get child comments

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have the following MySQL table:

```
Table  Comment:
  id int not null,
  parent_id int not null,
  body text not null,
  created datetime not null
```

parent_id is a recursive relationship. Never mind about whether it is nullable or not, since I can always assign a dummy id if no parent.

I want to select child comments for each parent (the most recent 5 for each parent).

If I use something like

```
SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE parent_id in (...) ORDER BY created DESC
```

That will select all comments for each specified parent, which I do not want.

I want to select the parents as well as first-degree children (at most 5)
in a single query or in the most efficient way.

Any Idea?

Comment: there is any `parent` table ?

Answer (score 0):

parent_id not null?? And if I want a post a new Comment which in fact its going to be a parent comment? This attribute will be 0 or what?

I think, i dont probe the sentence:

```
select * from comment as c where c.id=NUMBER and c.parent_id in (Select id from comment as c2 where c.parent_id = c2.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Comment AS p
WHERE id IN (...)                          -- list of parent IDs

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    c.*
FROM
    ( SELECT id AS parent_id
      FROM Comment 
      WHERE id IN (...)                   -- list of parent IDs
    ) AS d
  JOIN
    Comment AS c
      ON  c.parent_id = d.parent_id
      AND c.created >= COALESCE(
          ( SELECT ci.created
            FROM Comment AS ci
            WHERE ci.parent_id = d.parent_id
            ORDER BY ci.created DESC
            LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
          ), '1000-01-01')

ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(parent_id, id),
    c.created  ;
```

An index on `(parent_id, created)` will help efficiency.

Comment: The `COALESCE()` function is there to replace the NULL for the cases when a parent comment has less than 5 subcomments. It will be applied as many times as the number of parent IDs in your list.